# Checking if large string contains value within binary database column returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql

so i have a binary column in mysql that contains the number 2. I have done the query "select * from malwareTable". Now i have a string "2" and i want to check if that string contain a subset of the sequences from my database. However, when i do:

```
if (strpos($entire, $row['sequence']) !== false)
        {
            echo $row['malwareName']. ": ". $row['sequence']. "<br>";
            $none = $row['malwareName']. ": ". $row['sequence'];
        }
```

, nothing is returned. how will i get the test2 row to be returned? $entire contains my string "2".

```
+-------------+----------------------+
| malwareName | sequence             |
+-------------+----------------------+
| omega       | 01110101111110110111 |
| test2       | 2                    |
+-------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: What is `$entire` ?!

Comment: $entire contains my string "2"

Comment: Well you should post a little more of your code, is $row even filled?